# Efficiently sorting a list of slice

Tags: sorting, go

I have a function that copies data from map[string] string and make a slice from it. The function is below:

```
type Tags map[string]string

func createtraffic(tags []Tags) []interface{} {
    IDs := make([]interface{}, len(tags))
    for i := range tags {
        id, err := strconv.ParseUint(tags[i]["id"], 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        IDs[i] = id
    }
    return IDs
}
```

Now I want to sort Ids in increasing order of 'id'.

I am not sure if I should sort it after this for loop or since I am already looping on the map, I should sort within this loop.
which one should i go for(the len of map is somewhere 10K-20K) and what type of sort should i use?

Comment: Just use `sort.Strings`

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Just do a normal `sort.Slice`, and if that's not fast enough for your needs, then do benchmarks on alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In you case after `strconv.ParseUint` you have value `uint64` so it's better to have slice `[]uint64` not `[]interface{}` because it's way easier to sort.

So you can do something like this:

```
func createtraffic(tags []Tags) interface{} {
    IDs := make([]uint64, len(tags))
    for i := range tags {
        id, err := strconv.ParseUint(tags[i]["id"], 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        IDs[i] = id
    }

    sort.Slice(IDs, func(i, j int) bool { return IDs[i] < IDs[j] })

    return IDs
}
```

In case you still need `[]interface{}` you may do something like this:

```
func createtraffic(tags []Tags) []interface{} {
    IDs := make([]interface{}, len(tags))
    for i := range tags {
        id, err := strconv.ParseUint(tags[i]["id"], 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        IDs[i] = id
    }

    sort.Slice(IDs, func(i, j int) bool { return IDs[i].(uint64) < IDs[j].(uint64) })

    return IDs
}
```

**PS:** Here I've just added `sort.Slice` and updated `IDs` type.

I haven't changed anything else because this question about sorting, but there are rooms for improvements (loop, return type, ...) which are out of this question scope.

Comment: Thanks,  but i want the return type to be interface{}. Here the return type is []uint64

Comment: I have used datatype of IDs as IDs := make([]interface{}, len(tags)) and change the sort function  to sort.Slice(tagIDs, func(i, j int) bool { return tagIDs[i].(int64) < tagIDs[j].(int64) }). I guess this should be good enough?? should i use tagIDs[i].(int64) < tagIDs[j].(int64) or tagIDs[i].(int) < tagIDs[j].(int), this i am not sure of?? My numbers are very big have around 12-14 length.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think it's better to stick with uint64.

Answer (score 0):

Your best call is to sort `IDs` slice before returning from function. As [cn007b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3612353/cn007b) pointed out just use sort library to do it

```golang
sort.Slice(IDs, func(i, j int) bool { return IDs[i].(uint64) < IDs[j].(uint64) })
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this article https://golang.org/pkg/sort/. The example of sorting based on the key sounds to be what you are trying to do with your slice. Then calling the key type of sort you have your Less, Swap, and Len functions that are called by your Sort(). this allows you to sort by a specific Key.